# Display same data again and again in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my LINQ code:

```
    public JsonResult getfull()
    {
        var coursename = Session["course"].ToString();
        var location = Session["location"].ToString();
        var result = (from insti in db.Institute_Master
                      join course in db.Course_Detail on insti.InstituteId equals course.InstituteId
                      join coursemaster in db.Course_Master on course.CourseId equals coursemaster.CourseId
                      join  facility in db.Facility_Detail  on insti.InstituteId  equals facility.InstituteId
                      join  masterfacility in db.Facility_Master on facility.FacilityMasterID equals masterfacility.FacilityMasterId
                      where coursemaster.CourseName == coursename || insti.City == location
                      select new
                      {
                          //Id = insti.InstituteId,
                          name = insti.InstituteName,
                          university = insti.University,
                          Contact = insti.ContactNo,
                          address = insti.Address,
                          email = insti.EmailId,
                          zipcode = insti.Zipcode,
                          country = insti.Country,
                          state = insti.State,
                          city = insti.City,
                          start = insti.EstablishOn,
                          image = insti.ProfilePhoto,
                          fees = course.TotalFees,
                          mode = course.Mode,
                          coursename = coursemaster.CourseName,
                          duaration = coursemaster.duration,
                          discription = coursemaster.Discription,
                          eligibility = coursemaster.Eligibility,
                          recognization = coursemaster.Recognization,
                          facility  = masterfacility.FacilityName


                      }).Distinct();

        ViewBag.facilies = list;

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This method is return json result which is handled by angular js and I mention angularjs code below.

I am using AngularJs To display a data and my record is repeating for particular facility.

This is my tables:

[image]

This is a problem that display same record again for his facility:
[image]

This is my Angularjs code

```
    <h1>Show Institute</h1>
<div data-ng-app="myModule">
    <div data-ng-controller="myController">
<ul class="w3-ul w3-card-4" data-ng-repeat="detail in employees">
 <li class="w3-padding-16 institute-list">
    <span class="w3-xlarge">{{detail.name | uppercase}}</span>,<span>{{detail.address}}</span><br>
    <img alt="image" src="~/images/{{detail.image}}" class="w3-left  w3-margin-right img-institute-list" style="width:60px" />
    <span class="w3-xlarge">{{detail.coursename | uppercase}}</span>,<span>Course Duration {{detail.duaration}}</span>,<span>Course Mode  {{detail.mode}}</span>,<span>{{detail.discription}}</span><br>
    <span><b>Fees : </b>INR {{detail.fees}}</span><br>
    <span><b>{{detail.recognization | uppercase}}</b>  Recognised</span><br>


     <span>Facility {{detail.facility}}</span>
    <button class="w3-btn w3-blue" id="detail">More Details</button>


  </li>

      <script>
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $("button").click(function () {
                  $("#moredetail").toggle();
              });
          });
     </script>

    <li class="w3-padding-16 institute-list" id="moredetail" style="display:none">
        <span class="w3-xlarge">{{detail.contact}}</span>   <span class="w3-xlarge">{{detail.email}}</span><br />
         <span class="w3-xlarge" >{{detail.zipcode}}</span> <span class="w3-xlarge" >{{detail.country}}</span>  <br/>
         <span class="w3-xlarge" >{{detail.state}}</span> <span class="w3-xlarge" >{{detail.city}}</span>       <br />
          <span class="w3-xlarge" >{{detail.start}}</span>,
    </li>
</ul>

    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular
        .module("myModule", [])
        .controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) {

            $http.get("/home/getfull")
                 .then(function (response) {
                     $scope.employees = response.data;
                 });
        })
</script>  

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This code is for displaying data in a view view json method 
Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

It keeps adding the same record because you have "select new".  What you need is model like:

```
public class CourseModel
{
                          public int InstituteId {get; set;}
                         public string InstituteName {get; set;}
                          public string University {get; set;}
                          ETC...
}
```

Then in your MVC Controller:

```
 var result = (from insti in db.Institute_Master
                          join course in db.Course_Detail on insti.InstituteId equals course.InstituteId
                          join coursemaster in db.Course_Master on course.CourseId equals coursemaster.CourseId
                          join  facility in db.Facility_Detail  on insti.InstituteId  equals facility.InstituteId
                          join  masterfacility in db.Facility_Master on facility.FacilityMasterID equals masterfacility.FacilityMasterId
                          where coursemaster.CourseName == coursename || insti.City == location

var courses = new List<CourseModel>();
foreach(var c in result)
{
courses.Add(new CourseModel
{
                        InstitueName = insti.InstituteName,
                        University = insti.University,
                        ETC...
});
}

return Json(courses, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for your reponce but the code you have writen it gives error Like a query body end with select or group only